# Unrecognized option "firewall_name" under "hwi_oauth"

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

After upgrade of my project to symfony 2.8 I get the following error when I push the code to staging server.

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   Unrecognized option "firewall_name" under "hwi_oauth"
>   When i remove `firewall_name` option then I get an error that the option is required.

If someone provide some insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: make sure you have HwiOauthBundle properly installed (composer.json, AppKernel.php) on staging environment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get this error now because when You was updating `Symfony` rest of dependencies was updated also.

This option was renamed to `firewall_names` to support multiple firewalls in this commit: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/commit/9bdbc089ddffede12a5b575a441c4e0fa2ee9dd7 and released as part of [0.4.0 version](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/releases/tag/0.4.0).

Now it's value must be array. Example:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
```

Comment: Thank you! that was the issue, much appreciated.